# Multiple asynctasks in android

Tags: android, opencv

I want to run 2 method simultaneously. However it show only the output of second method. Can you help me?

ImageView imgView;

ImageView imgView2;

public void loadImageToImageView(){ imgView.setImageBitmap(currentBitmap);}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)

```
public void DrawLetter() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Draw(); 
            Draw2();
            return currentBitmap;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            if(bitmap!=null) {

                loadImageToImageView();
            }
        }
    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're running this task twice.  But the two times are going to load the result into the same image view.  That means whichever finishes first will be overwritten by the one that finishes second.  If you want to see both, you need to use two separate image views.

Comment: You mean Draw and Draw2 shouldnt return currentBitmap. But how? I mean I want to see both same picture

Comment: No, I mean loadImageToImageView() needs to load to two separate image views.

Comment: I updated my question. And I dont understand the way?public void loadImageToImageView(){ imgView.setImageBitmap(currentBitmap);imgView2.setImageBitmap(currentBitmap);}  Should I use like that?

Comment: Should I create 2 different  loadImageToImageView()  loadImageToImageView2() like that and different imageview or in  loadImageToImageView()  and 2 diferent imageview because it does nt work